# Airflow BranchPythonOperator chaining

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying to use Airflow BranchPythonOperator. I got the error:

```
def next_task(x):
  if x : return "branch_data"
  else: return "branch_no_data"

branch_task  = BranchPythonOperator(
   task_id = 'branch_task',
   python_callable = next_task,
   op_args = [x],
   dag = dag
)

branch_no_data=DummyOperator(task_id="branch_no_data", dag=dag)
branch_data=DummyOperator(task_id="branch_data", dag=dag)
join_task=DummyOperator(task_id="join_task", dag=dag)
branch_task >> [branch_data, branch_no_data ]  >>  join_task
```

I need only one of the 2 tasks (branch_data, branch_no_data) to be executed.
Below is my failed attempt to implement the tasks chaining.
I got the error:

```
branch_task >> [branch_data, branch_no_data ]  >>  join_task
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'BranchPythonOperator' and 'list'
```

Comment: If you will use : branch_task >> [branch_data, branch_no_data ] then it should work but if you have some tasks after branching then you should use : branch_task >> branch_data  >>  join_task and in next line : branch_task >> branch_no_data  >>  join_task

Comment: Thanks, Priya, it helps. In my case the the entire chain was a part of return statement:
return (branch_task >> [branch_data, branch_no_data ]  >>  join_task)
How to adjust return accordingly your recommendation?

Comment: I don't think i understand the ask properly. Can you show a visual representation of tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Airflow does not allow you to link a list into another task.
One task can output into a list of tasks but a list of tasks cannot be linked into a single task. Hence the error of the `>>` operand not being supported for the `list` type.

It might be a good idea to just write out the chain separately without the list both for your own clarity and to avoid any potential issues.

2 versions of your code that will work are:

```
branch_task >> branch_data    >> join_task
branch_task >> branch_no_data >> join_task
```

Or

```
branch_task    >> [ branch_data, branch_no_data ]
branch_data    >> join_task
branch_no_data >> join_task
```

Comment: You can fan out to a list of tasks using the `chain` function.